# Visual C++ assertion failure

Tags: c++, assertion

I am creating a program to copy a text file. I have a main.cpp file which reads in a text file given by the filenamein array and then output a copy of the text file given by the filenameout array. i have this function declared in my FileUtilities.h as

```
bool textFileCopy(char filenamein[], char filenameout[]);
```

Then the FileUtilities.cpp contains

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

#include "FileUtilities.h"

bool FileUtilities::textFileCopy(char filenamein[], char filenameout[])
{
    ifstream fin(filenamein);
    if(fin.is_open())
    {
        ofstream fout(filenameout);
    
        char c;
        while(fin.good())
        {
            fin.get(c);
            fout << c;
        }

        fout.close();
        fin.close();

        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

When I compile this I get a Visual C assertion failure. I get a dialog box titled "Microsoft Visual C++ debug library" which contains the following:

> "Debug Assertion Failed!
>
> Program: .....Parser.exe
>
> file f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\Self_x86\crt\src\fopen.c
>
> Line 53
>
> Expression: (file!=NULL)"

This error gives me 3 options: Abort, Retry or Ignore.
Abort just stops the debug. Retry brings up a message in Visual Studio which says "program.exe has triggered a breakpoint". If I click break here Visual Studio opens a file called "fopen.c" and points to line 54 in this file.

If I continue from this point Visual Studio opens another file called "dbghook.c" with a pointer to line 62.

Comment: well, obviously, `filenamein` or `filenameout` is NULL pointer.. Show us how you call `textFileCopy`.

Comment: you should copy the file in big chunks instead of char by char.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where's the error? On `fin` or `fout`? Check the corresponding `filenameXX`, it must not be `NULL`

Comment: i fixed it now, the file name was set to null in my main.cpp file. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Either `filenamein` or `filenameout` out is null, hence the error.  If you use `std::string` instead of C strings, you won't have to worry about null pointers.  Since you are already using the C++ I/O library, there's really no reason not to use `std::string`.

That said, your function is also incorrect because you don't check whether the `get()` call succeeded before using the extracted character.  You also return `true`, even if the copy fails part way through the file.

The following is a correct implementation of this function (note, however, that it is almost assuredly not optimal; it just demonstrates how to correctly write the function that you have):

```
bool textFileCopy(std::string filenamein, std::string filenameout)
{
    // Open the input stream
    std::ifstream in(filenamein.c_str());
    if (!in)
        return false;

    // Open the output stream
    std::ofstream out(filenameout.c_str());
    if (!out)
        return false;

    // Do the copy
    char c;
    while (in.get(c) && out.put(c));

    // Ensure that the whole file was copied successfully
    return in.eof() && out;

}   // The input and output streams are closed when the function returns
```